# Solving an Undefined Projection for US Counties (1990)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, shapefile

After inserting the cs99_d90.shp file obtained from the 1990 US Census, I received an error message claiming:

> The following data sources you added are missing spatial reference
>   information. This data can be be drawn in ArcMap but cannot be
>   projected.

After reading about several tools, such as the Define Projection tool which requires me to choose a projection from a list of projections that I cannot comprehend, I am hoping there is a much less convoluted solution to this problem. I have the 1990 County shapefile, and I want to layer it over a base map.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's a geographic (longitude/latitude) coordinate system.  The raw tiger line files (see chapter 3 in the [doc](https://www2.census.gov/geo/docs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgr92/)) use the NAD27 datum, so it might be [EPSG:4267](https://epsg.io/4267).